# Scalaworksheet - Why does it say "Cannot resolve symbol Employee" in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

[image: Cannot Resolve symbol]

I compiled a simple "Employee" class file in scala using the following command at command prompt and it created a Employee.class file also. So no issues in compilation. But when I try to create an object of that Employee class in a separate script file, in IntelliJ is shows "cannot resolved symbol Employee" . why is that ?

scalac Employee.sc

Comment: If the definition of `Employee` is in a different file or package or object then you have to `import` it to bring it into scope.

Comment: In the script file I typed Import Employee. Even then it says "Can't resolve symbol Employee"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the worksheets don't have scope of each other. From your screenshot Employee.sc is its own worksheet - why don't you try to make Employee a regular Scala class (.scala) - compile that, then try to declare it in a worksheet.
I was able to successfully do this with a quick test:

[image]

Comment: I will try that. Thanks